# altering privilege in psql interactive prompt

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, alter-table

I am new to the use of `psql` prompt. I ran `sudo -u postgres` (`psql` version 9.3.9)

Then I connected to my database and I ran

```
=> ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER some_user IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO other_user;
```

and then I got this error message

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER"
LINE 1: ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER ckan_default IN SCHEMA pub..
```

How can I deal with that ?

Comment: and what is the original intent?.. What are you trying to grant?

Comment: Why `\gset` it? It won't return a useful or informative result anyway.

Comment: @CraigRinger I have edited my post - still throwing the same error !

Comment: I think you want: `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES in schema public grant select on all tables to other_user`. It doesn't make sense to change the default privileges for one user if all you want to do is give the other user select privileges

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I got it from there : https://lists.okfn.org/pipermail/ckan-dev/2012-October/003227.html

Comment: @VaoTsun it is explained here : https://lists.okfn.org/pipermail/ckan-dev/2012-October/003227.html